# Index hints with SSMS for Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

In SSMS for traditional SQL Serer, you get hints for missing indexes in the Actual Execution Plan. 
(It shows `create index`statements.)

However, when connecting to an Azure SQL Database , it seems this functionality is missing. Is there an other way to get hints about missing indexes and speeding up queries?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the missed index details using [sys.dm_db_missing_index_details (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-missing-index-details-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): Returns detailed information about missing indexes, excluding spatial indexes.

There are 3 primary DMVs which provide information about the Missing Indexes:

```
--Returns detailed information about missing indexes
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_details

--Returns information about what missing indexes are contained in a specific missing index group
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups

--Returns summary information about groups of missing indexes
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats
```

For more details you could reference:

1. [sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-missing-index-groups-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): This DMV returns information about indexes that are missing in a specific index group, except for spatial indexes.
2. [sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-missing-index-group-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): Returns summary information about groups of missing indexes, excluding spatial indexes.

Other reference: [Identifying Missing Indexes in SQL Server](https://samirbehara.com/2017/08/23/identifying-missing-indexes-in-sql-server/).

Hope this helps.